# Synchronous call in typescript for angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

I'm currently stucked with a problem in my application.
I'm trying to read multiple JSON files, but the method to read them all, returns before all files are read.

arrJsonPathFinal is the list of JSON files.

```
Promise.all(arrJsonPathFinal.map(url =>
  fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json())
)).then(jsonValue => {
  jsonValue.forEach((json, index) => {
    strJsonData += '"' + arrJsonPath[index] + '":' + JSON.stringify(jsonValue[index]) + ",";
  });
  return JSON.parse("{" + strJsonData.substring(0, strJsonData.length - 1) + "}");
});
```

Do you have any idea how to manage this to work out?
Tried to find a solution with observables and promises aswell, but so far, I'm clueless.

Comment: What do you mean by "the method to read them all"? The code above is in a function and you expect is to return the result of `return JSON.parse("{" + strJsonData.substring(0, strJsonData.length - 1) + "}");` line? According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you still get a `Promise` and you have to `then()` it or `await` it or something. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-i2yrtj !

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all(arrJsonPathFinal.map(url =>
  fetch(url)
)).then(resps => {
      resps.forEach((resp, index) => {
          jsonValue=> resp.json())
          strJsonData += '"' + arrJsonPath[index] + '":' + 
             JSON.stringify(jsonValue[index]) + ",";
   });
    return JSON.parse("{" + strJsonData.substring(0, strJsonData.length - 1) + 
   "}");
 });
```

Comment: This is not working for me, because the code itself is showing some errors. index is unknown etc.